# Can't import wx(Python) on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, import, wxpython

It is first time I'm using python on mac. I installed Python 2.7.1 from python.org and then wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7

(Mac OS X 10.6.6)

I have no idea where they installed to, but anyway, that's what I get:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.11.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.11.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.11.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core_.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.11.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core_.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As FogleBird says, wxPython use 32-bit and Mac Python installer should offer both architectures. 
So invoking python with 32 bit should allow you to use it with no issue.
to invoke Python in 32-bit

```
$ python2.7-32
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> print wx.version()
2.8.12.1 (mac-unicode)
```

instead of just $ python

Comment: Yet another option: `arch -i386 python`

Comment: and another option: `export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 32-bit Python to use wxPython.

> These binaries should work on all
>   versions of OSX from 10.3.9 onwards on
>   either PPC or i386 architectures.
>   Since they use the Carbon API they are
>   limited to running in 32-bit mode.

Comment: First I installed 64 bit version. Now I just tried reinstall python 32 bit, but when I see sys.maxint - it's 64 bit. Still wx does not work.