# Can not import wxPython (Mac)

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, osx-lion

I thought I'd move from using Tkinter to wxPython, but I'm having some troubles. All I get is this:

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wx
```

I have installed wxPython. When I run the uninstaller I clearly see that wxPython IS installed:

```
  1.  wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7                 3.0.0.0

Enter the number of the install to examine or 'Q' to quit:
```

When I start Python I see that my version should match the version of wxPython:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I'm on OS X 10.7.5 32-bit.

Any help would be awesome! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't import wx(Python) on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798759/cant-import-wxpython-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Running python with the commands given in that post does not solve my problem.

Comment: wxpython on a Mac is a little bit of a nuisance, due to apple's pre-installed python.   Are you sure that you are running the instance of python into which you installed wx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macs can have multiple versions of Python installed.  Are you sure that you installed wxPython for the same python you invoke with the interpreter?

Try, `which python`, and make sure that this version of python has a `wxredirect.pth` file in `site-packages` pointing to the wxPython installation.  (If it doesn't search for `wxredirect.pth`.)

Here's one version on my system...

```
> which python2.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6

> more /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wxredirect.pth
import site; site.addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.0.0/lib/python2.6')
#import site; site.addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.1.1/lib/python2.6')
#import site; site.addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.6')
```

Here, btw, I can comment out lines in the `wxredirect.pth` to choose the version of wxPython I want to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I find site-packages? I searched in finder but found no such file. I'm really new to the whole coding thing, plus I've been on windows my entire life.

Comment: `site-packages` is a standard directory where packages not contained in the standard distribution are put (you should also have a `site-packages` directory in Windows, btw).  Mine show up in the finder, but this might be due to Finder settings.  Look on a path similar to mine: use `which python`, back up from that directory (to the directory above `bin`) and into `lib`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just find the same problem.
I used `brew install wxpython` to install it on mac.
I try the method above but no use.
I happen to find the solution when I install another package, it showen below:

```
   brew install tbb
   Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/tbb-2017_U7.sierra.bottle.t
   ############################################################ 100.0%
   ==> Pouring tbb-2017_U7.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
   ==> Caveats
   Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
   in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
   this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
   please run:

   mkdir -p /Users/ningrongye/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-        
   packages")' >> /Users/ningrongye/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
   packages/homebrew.pth`
```

this is what homebrew said and I just try those, and it works.

ningrong

Answer (score 0):

I have Python 2.7 and 3.7 .
In `/usr/local/bin/` there are symbolic links for 2.7 and 3.7 Python versions and also symbolic links for pip.

I've installed wxPython with pip3

```
pip3 install -U wxPython
```

Then i checked the installation for Python3

```
myname$ python3
Python 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'4.0.4 osx-cocoa (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5'
```

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by resetting the brew environment to 2.7:

```
brew link --overwrite python@2
```